# How to check a number inside a span and change its color based on the value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is what I have. It isn't reading the value correctly.

http://jsfiddle.net/neowot/7o87wrsy/

HTML:

```
<a class="InterestLink">Click me</a>

<div id="InterestExpander">
            <div id="InterestExpanderX">
                &times;
            </div>

            <br><br>

            General Rating: 
            <span class="RatingGeneralNumber">80%</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
<a class="InterestLink">Click me</a>

<div id="InterestExpander">
            <div id="InterestExpanderX">
                &times;
            </div>

            <br><br>

            General Rating: 
            <span class="RatingGeneralNumber">80%</span>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.InterestLink').click(function() {
    $('#InterestExpander').fadeIn(450);

    if (parseInt($('.RatingGeneralNumber').val()) > 50 ) {
        $('.RatingGeneralNumber').css({"color":"green"});
    }

}); 



$('#InterestExpanderX').click(function() {
    $('#InterestExpander').fadeOut(250);
});
```

Also, another question while I'm here. This site will have links to multiple different movies. Each time they click on a movie link, the same div will pop up, but with a rating unique to the movie based on what the database says.

Would the span be containing the movie rating be more appropriate as an "ID" or "Class" type, or neither?

Comment: only input elements have values, so use .text() instead of .val()

Comment: Worth noting that it's [recommended to use the radix parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_interpretations_with_no_radix) if you're using `parseInt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `text()` instead of `val` span elements use `text()`

```js
    $('.InterestLink').click(function() {
        $('#InterestExpander').fadeIn(450);
        
        if (parseInt($('.RatingGeneralNumber').text()) > 50 ) {
            $('.RatingGeneralNumber').css({"color":"green"});
        }
     
    }); 



    $('#InterestExpanderX').click(function() {
        $('#InterestExpander').fadeOut(250);
    });
```

```css
.InterestLink {
}

#InterestExpander {
    color:white;
    background-color:#484848;
    position:fixed;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:700px;
    height:480px;
    display:none;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 0px #000000;
}

 
#InterestExpanderX {
    float:right;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:50px;
}


.RatingGeneralNumber{
    display:block;
    font-size:22px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="InterestLink">Click me</a>

<div id="InterestExpander">
            <div id="InterestExpanderX">
                &times;
            </div>
         
            <br><br>
                   
            General Rating: 
            <span class="RatingGeneralNumber">80%</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly. :] I will accept it as "Solved" as soon as stackoverflow lets me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace `$(".RatingGeneralNumber").val()` by `$(".RatingGeneralNumber").text()`, because `val()` only for `form` children element like: `input`, `textarea`, `option` element. Try this and your code will work perfecty! :)

Comment: _"only for input element"_ ... and `<select>` and `<textarea>`, but yes.

Comment: So For form children element is the right expression! :) I will edit my anwser